# Undefined index with $_POST data and value of -1

Tags: php, arrays, post

Any reason why PHP is throwing a warning 'undefined index' when post data is set as -1?

```
print_r($_POST);
// returns
Array ( [id] => -1 [colour] => red )
// warning occurs on following line
if($_POST['id'] != 0){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works flawlessly:

```
<?php

$_POST = array(
    'id' => '-1',
    'colour' => 'red',
);

print_r($_POST); // returns Array ( [id] => -1 [colour] => red )
// No warning occurs on following line
if($_POST['id'] != 0){
    // ...
}
```

The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, please add more info @xylar and the *exact* error message please

Comment: @Pekka @Álvaro G. Vicario my mistake - the problem was the form had 2 products the first with -1 went through no problem but the 2nd product had no info and thus produced the error! Doh!